# Sample ReactJS from reactjs.org code not working with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I am trying to follow the code sample given in this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute to run a react component into an existing HTML page.

but when I am trying to replace the native `JavaScript` with `JSX` I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: e is not defined

I know I need to replace the `e(LikeButton))` with something. but it's not mentioned there what to update in render code.

likebutton.js:

```
'use strict';

// const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    // Display a "Like" <button>
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true })}>
        Like
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!-- Load React. -->
<!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load our React component. -->

<script src="{{ asset('theme_assets/js/react/likebutton.js') }}" type="text/babel"></script>

<script>
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly where? but I don't think it will work, because the `e` is not defined anywhere. so what to replace instead of `e(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

With

```
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, domContainer);
```

Working Code here
https://jsbin.com/wuqoluyovu/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Worked..! but I need to move the `querySelector` 2 lines code into the component. But why this most important step is missing in the official document?

Comment: I'd agree that this is missing from official documentation, however, as per the API it is expected to pass on a react element as the first argument.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

Comment: The documentation is for someone who is first-time implementor and trying to work with the React for 1st time. then it should not be considered that the person is very well known to react and gone through the API documentations. Thanks anyways...!